# Rosyln versus T4 for code generation

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, t4, roslyn

So I have a lot of knowledge invested in T4. I've wrote a few code generators of varying complexity and generally love it with the caveat of code-generating-code being difficult to unit test(but I worked around that somewhat even). Now though, I've been hearing more and more about the Rosyln project. I've heard a lot of things it supposedly does. Syntax analysis, use as a scripting language etc, and also some kind of code generation (though I think it happens at runtime rather than compile time)

How do these two very different technologies stack up? Other than T4 being stable *today*, which should generally be "the default" for code generators?

In what ways do they differ and what are the pros and cons of going with either method?

Comment: Roslyn is a nice idea, but it's been vaporware for awhile.  T4 is more or less equivalent to "compile-time macro expansion," so its use case is going to be different.

Comment: As written, this question is not constructive. Perhaps you can edit it to ask some more specific questions about Roslyn vs. T4?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Roslyn is vaporware? There's a CTP and things built on it already! lol

Comment: Given that this question has been asked by someone who's been here as long as I have, with 10K+ reputation, I have to conclude that we are either not educating adequately or not enforcing adequately.

Comment: The CTP, by its own admission, states that it is feature incomplete, and Anders announced it, like, two years ago.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm confused. I didn't think it was a shopping question. There is a clear-ish answer (list of pros/cons of each). What part of this is non-constructive? Does this lean to much toward discussion?

Comment: The operative word being "list."  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wasn't aware a pros/cons list was obviously inappropriate. Even if that is the official stance, it'd help to be consistent. By a quick search of "pros cons" you can see similar list questions that weren't closed as recent as December 2012. Exaclty what makes this form of list question different and/or inappropriate?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25183/discussion-between-earlz-and-robert-harvey)

Comment: Although closed; I Think Roslyn adds value to T4 rather than replace it. Sometimes one wants get a C# syntax tree from a text-file and generate code from that. Roslyn can do that for you.

Comment: From my own experience as of 2018: I prefer Roslyn than T4 templates. T4 templates are slow, freezing everything when running them on big database, no official editing capabilities for .tt files.

Comment: I recommend using something like https://github.com/martinjw/dbschemareader and generating it yourself.

Comment: Also take a look at Testura.Code, it's a wrapper over Roslyn.